# Windows 10 per app equalizer

Tags: windows, audio, spotify, equalizer, dolbydigital

Equalizer APO (and the Dolby EQ app that I've also tried) seems to only be working globally, i.e. once I enable it, the entire system and every single program uses it. That messes up certain things like OBS audio when I'm streaming or recording. Sounds become muffled, some audio gets equalized multiple times - first by the music player, then by OBS, then by the viewers' computers etc.

For this reason (and as a personal preference), I don't want to equalize most programs, save for the few specific ones, like Spotify (which for some reason still lacks an inbuilt eq). How could I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can kinda hack your way around this. First, on Windows 10 v1803, you can [pick a audio output device per-app](https://www.howtogeek.com/352787/how-to-set-per-app-sound-outputs-in-windows-10/). This means you can send e.g. Spotify through a specific output device.

With that knowledge, you need to create a *virtual audio device*. This is a "fake" sound output that can be used to loop the sound back to an input, or send it to a hardware output ... and you can insert an equaliser into the mix :)

There are several ways you can accomplish this. The traditional solution would have been [Virtual Audio Cable](http://www.ntonyx.com/vac.htm) with a separate per-device equaliser like [Equalizer APO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/), but this is rather complex (and not free). Nowadays there is [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) (free), which provides the virtual audio devices (built-in) and a basic equaliser, and can integrate with Equalizer APO if you want a more full-featured one.

Or, for Spotify speficically, there is [Equalify](https://www.equalify.me/). I'm not certain how it works or how well it works - YMMV.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The Configurator for Equalizer APO doesn't pickup Virtual Inputs from Voicemeeter. Equalizer APO only applies to the Hardware Outs.

Comment: @Myath Equalizer APO should have direct integration with Voicemeeter such that it directly lists Voicemeeter channels in its configurator. In the past, there were some reports that this may not work correctly depending on how you installed Voicemeeter, and doing a full uninstall => reboot => install cycle can help. That said, I've not actually needed to use any of these for a couple years now, so you're probably better off either asking a new question or asking on the Equalizer APO support pages directly.

Comment: Voicemeeter Banana now provides a six-band parametric EQ per output on top of the bass/treble setting per virtual input. Not what I would call “basic“. 